# Web API OData with EntityFramework exposing only DTOs

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I prefer not to expose my Entity Framework models and my controllers expose DTO style objects.

I have tried to have my controller's Get method's to be

```
  public IQueryable<PersonDTO> Get(ODataQueryOptions<PersonDTO> query )
```

buy I don't know how to apply ODataQueryOptions to db.Persons so that the filtering happens in the SQL.

I ended up with

```
public IQueryable<PersonDTO> Get(ODataQueryOptions<PersonEF> query )
    {
        using (var db = new AppDbContext())
        {
            var result = (query.ApplyTo(db.Persons) as IQueryable<PersonEF>).Select
                (c => new PersonDTO()
                {
                    FirstName = c.FirstName,
                    LastName = c.LastName,
                    DateOfBirth = c.DateOfBirth,
                    Gender = c.Gender
                }

                );
            return result.ToList().AsQueryable();
        }
    }
```

In order for this to work I have both classes added to `ODataConventionModelBuilder`: in my Register method.

```
 ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
 builder.EntitySet<PersonDTO>("PersonDTO");
 builder.EntitySet<PersonEF>("Person");
```

How can I expose only PersonDTO and apply the ODataQueryOptions filters to EF's PersonEF?